# Show that a sequence is increasing or decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis

I know from Calc II that a sequence is increasing if $a_n < a_n+1$ for all $n \geq 1$. A sequence is decreasing if $a_n > a_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

I am considering the sequence $\dfrac{1}{2n}$, and want to show it is increasing. We know $2n < 2n+2$ which implies $\dfrac{1}{2n} > \dfrac{1}{2n+2}$. Hence, $a_n > a_{n+1}$ showing that the sequence is decreasing, but Wolfram alpha says this sequence increases. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you put $1/(2n)$ or $1/2n$ in it?

Comment: Can you cite the Wolfram Alpha link?  I wonder if maybe you are testing the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{2}n\right\}$ instead of $\left\{\frac{1}{2n}\right\}$

Comment: Someone change my edit if it's wrong.

Comment: I tried both and got increasing for both. Edit: nevermind, no I didn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you entered $1/2n$ which WolframAlpha took to be $\frac 12 n$. In terms of order of operations, since division and multiplication have equal precedence, the convention is to apply operations left to right. So $1/2n$ is calculated as $(1/2)\cdot n$.

You are correct that the sequence is decreasing. As the denominator increases, the subsequent terms decrease.

Always try to avoid ambiguities by surrounding sums in the numerator and/or denominator, or products in the denominator, with parentheses.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+1%2F%282n%29+increasing%3F .. So apparently it's still increasing?

Comment: Javier: that's not an answer to your question (the link). If it were, it would be a Boolean answer (yes or no). "increasing" is given as a link for further clarification of the query.

Comment: I see that now, thanks. I put in the sequences themselves and saw geometrically that 1/(2n) is decreasing. The original reason for my confusion was that one of my homework questions says to show this sequence is increasing (among other things), but I guess that was a typo of sorts.

Comment: You certainly reasoned correctly, and seem to understand the task. Trust yourself a bit more ;-)